# Encoding urls containing emoji icons

Tags: ios, url, encoding, urlencode, nsurl

Unable to prepare `NSURL` object with string containing emoji icons.

When I try to form `NSURL` using:

```
let urlString = "http://www.example.com/"
let URL = NSURL(string: urlString)
```

`URL` returned is nil, while the browser is able to open the valid webpage using same urlString.

I want to open it in UIWebView. So any idea like how to encode it properly to satisfy NSURL requirements?

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

**Update:** 
When I try to prepare NSURL object using the following string:

`let encodedURLString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

It works perfectly fine as `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding()` method converts illegal url-characters to legal representation. **But this is deprecated.**

Its alternative method `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters()` can be used but it will have to be called on different url components like:

```
// host: "www.example.com", path: "/" 
host.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
path.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet())
```

How can I get the url components(i.e host, path etc) from a string as when I try to create NSURL/NSURLComponents, it returns nil.(Reason being the malformed url string.)??

Comment: Good question! I'm currently trying to figure out a more general solution but in the mean time you can use `let escapedString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet())` and to create the url `let url = NSURL(string: escapedString!)`.